# How to load custom dataset to capsule network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am a newbie to deep learning and its frameworks. I have collected some jpg images of bicycle and bike object. Now, I wanted to train this images using capsule network.

Capsule network is implemented on mnist dataset. The code is [here](https://github.com/naturomics/CapsNet-Tensorflow).

What are the required changes to apply my custom dataset. Image should be changed to numpy format or tfrecord format? And how to load them on network?

Comment: As of today it is recommended to use Dataset API for input pipeline.  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets

Answer (score 0):

To load custom dataset, I refered [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/10/keras-tutorial-how-to-get-started-with-keras-deep-learning-and-python/). It helps. The dataset is converted to numpy array and keras background is used.

I load custom dataset and for capsule network model, use [this](https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras).